# render partial with username after a login

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, omniauth, omniauth-facebook

a rails app using devise omniauth to login an application.
After a success login, I would like to re place a "Login" button with html code that displayes the @current_user.email

```
      $(function() {
          $('#facebook-connect').click(function(e) {
              e.preventDefault();

              FB.login(function(response) {
                if(response.authResponse) {
                  $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: '/users/auth/facebook/callback',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    data: {signed_request: response.authResponse.signedRequest},
                    success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                      $('#loginout_button').html("<%= j render(:partial => 'account_info') %>");

                    },
                }
              }
              , {scope: 'email'});

          });
      });
```

And the partial:

```
    <% if user_signed_in? %>
    <p class="text-left small"><%=current_user.email%></p>
    <p class="text-left">
    <%= link_to destroy_user_session_path, :method => :delete do %>
        <%=t('auth.logout')%>
    <% end%>
```

But of course it wouldn't work because the partial rendered on page load and so it generetes the template of the loggedout user:

```
$('#loginout_button').html("  <li>\n  <button type=\"button\" onclick=\"openLoginModal(); return false;\">Login<\/button>\n  <\/li>\n");
```

how should you generate a template based on devise @current_user state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make another ajax request inside of `success` callback to load `account_info` template.

Comment: Took your advice!